# Can a puppeteer inside a docker container launch or connect with a headed chrome instance outside the container?

Tags: puppeteer

I would containerize my puppeteer application but sometime I would use headed chrome for debugging some changes on UI. I would add a launcher of chrome outside the container in case using headed chrome. I would write browser's wsEndpoint to a file in shared container's volume then use puppeteer to connect with browser via that file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you had the confs of Dockerfile and networking right ...